# Android String.format throwing UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have the following string resource:

```
<string formatted="false" name="residential_search_url">https://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Search/Property/Residential.json?latitude_min=%f%26latitude_max=%f%26longitude_min=%f%26longitude_max=%f</string>
```

This is being used in an Activity by:

```
String residentialUrl = task.getSearchUrl(_map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds,getString(R.string.residential_search_url));
```

And the method is defined as:

```
public String getSearchUrl(LatLngBounds bounds, String baseUrl){
        return String.format(baseUrl,
                bounds.southwest.latitude,
                bounds.northeast.latitude,
                bounds.southwest.longitude,
                bounds.northeast.longitude);
    }
```

I keep getting:

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = l''
```

I have also tried using `%s` in place of `%f` and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix was to use `&amp;` to escape the ampersand, instead of `%26`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of %26 as a part of the URL, not the %f format specifier.  %26 is not a valid format spec, so you get an error.  You need to tell the format routine that you actually do want a literal % character here.  Try %% for that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: I need to escape the ampersands in the query string. How do I do that? I thought it was %26 but evidently not?

Comment: I got it wrong - turned out it's escaped as `&amp;`. Now it's working just fine.

Comment: %26 would work in most situations, just not when you use the string as input to something that interprets % characters as format specifiers.  Sounds like you avoided the issue.

Comment: Rather confusing, especially coming from the .NET world!